# Как узнать какой элемент вызвал функцию обратного вызова?

Tags: lua

```
sec_list = "RSH3,VBZ2,O4Z2,O2Z2,SiM3,SiH3,SiF3,RIH3,RIM3,LKH3,LKZ2,GDZ2,GMZ2,GZH3,GZZ2,EuZ2,EDZ2,SiZ2,RIZ2,"
SecList = {}
SecList = string.split(sec_list, ",")

for i = 1, #SecList do
            local sec_code = SecList[i]
            local row = i   

            local errorDesc = ""
            DS, errorDesc = CreateDataSource(ClassCode, sec_code, Interval, "LAST") 
            if (DS == nil) then error(errorDesc) end
            if not DS: SetUpdateCallback(function(...) OnUpdate(...) end) then error("SetUpdateCallback") end

            metatable = {callback = sec_code, value = row}
            setmetatable(DS, metatable)
            metatable.__index = metatable

            TableDB[i] = DS

            PrintDbgStr(":: metatable: " .. tostring(getmetatable(TableDB[i]))) --> :: metatable: table: 071F82C0
            PrintDbgStr(":: sec_code: " .. tostring(TableDB[i].callback))       --> :: sec_code: RSH3
            PrintDbgStr(":: row: " .. tostring(TableDB[i].value))               --> :: row: 1

end

function OnUpdate()

    -- DS.value и DS.callback будут после цикла равны последнему в списке RIZ2
    if not SetTableCell(MyTable, DS.value, "Цена послед.", getParamEx(ClassCode, DS.callback, "LAST").param_image) then error("SetTableCell") end

    -- Как здесь узнать какой DS и его metatable из TableDB вызвал эту функцию?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас уже лямбда есть, добавьте туда параметр.

```
.... SetUpdateCallback(function(...) OnUpdate(sec_code) end)....

.... 
function OnUpdate(sec_code)....
```